# Etymology of 하십시오체 sentence endings

Tags: etymology, sentence-endings

What is the etymology of the 하십시오체 sentence endings?

- ~습니다
- ~습니까
- ~읍시오

Some conjecture on my part: The spelling of the indicative and interrogative endings makes me think that 습 and 니다/니까 were once separate, because the ㅂ is never actually pronounced as ㅂ. But it might have been just a choice made when the orthography was standardised.

Comment: -읍시다 is a 하오체 ending.

Comment: @Klmo Sorry, you're right. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is along the right track. The spelling of Middle Korean is well documented, and it was evidently a much more agglutinative language: in summary, it is descended from the Middle Korean `-ᅀᆞᇦᄂᆞᅌᅵ-` (Yale: *-zopno.ngi-*)

In Middle Korean, as well as the "slot" of subject/addressee honorification 시 (which hasn't changed much since), there is also a "slot" for **object exaltation / honorification**. This function was lost from the verbal morphology from the 17th century onwards, but before then it was the archaic hangeul syllable `ᄉᆞᆸ` (Yale: *sop*). The `ㅅ` [could assimilate to](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nVgr2BkwAdkC&pg=PA294) `ㅿ` (Yale: *z*) after nasals, liquids or vowels; or `ㅈ` (Yale: *c*) after *t*, *c* or *ch*. The final `ㅂ` could also become `ㅸ` (Yale: *W*), making the morpheme `ᅀᆞᇦ` (Yale: *zoW*) in intervocalic position.

As `ㅿ` would [later disappear across the language](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/293/how-does-15th-century-hangul-writing-type-differ-from-modern-hangul), as well as the *arae a* `ㆍ` after vowels, that left just the `ㅂ` portion in Modern Korean to represent this portion in verbs with stems ending in vowels or in `ㄹ`. As its function as object honorific had also reduced greatly, it just simply became part of the "하십시오체/합쇼체" speech level.

In (non-liquid) consonant stems, the `ㅈ` became `ㅅ` in this context, and the *arae a* ended up as the vowel `ᅳ` in such closed syllables, so that `ᄉᆞᆸ` became `습`.

The second part was the **continuative marker / processive marker** `-ᄂᆞ-` (Yale: *-no-*), which [reduced](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NN-yIdLOkCoC&pg=PA305) heavily across a lot of verbal endings. It ended up coalescing into the next morpheme in "하십시오체/합쇼체", but remained its own syllable in "하소서체", with its *arae a* becoming `ᅡ` instead.

Next is the **polite style marker** for Middle Korean: `ᅌᅵ` (Yale: *ngi*) [note that this is not `이`]. This velar nasal seems to have had very marginal position in native Korean words, and in this case appears to have changed to `ㄴ` while nasalising the preceding consonant. Most instances of `ᅌ` were resyllabified, making it the final `ㅇ` of a previous syllable [compare how 가히 *kahi* + ᅌᅡ지 *ngaci* became 강아지 (Yale: *kangaci*; RR: *gang-aji*)].

These three syllables were pretty much completely independent in Middle Korean, and the polite style was used [quite frequently](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2AmspKX3beoC&pg=PA209), even without object honorification:

> 그딋 ᄯᆞᄅᆞᆯ 맛고져 ᄒᆞ더ᅌᅵ다
>
> *kutuys stolol maskwocye hote-ngita*
>
> (He) has been wanting to meet your daughter

The -다 and -까 endings are derived directly from Middle Korean -다 and -ᆺ가 for declarative and interrogative sentences directly (although there were other endings that have become archaic in 21st-century Modern Korean).

The imperative ending -읍시오 was on the other hand *not* descended from Middle Korean, which [preferred using -쇼셔 instead](https://ko.dict.naver.com/seo.nhn?id=31460500) (which exhibited vowel harmony), although it bears resemblance to the 하소서체 speech level of Modern Korean. Instead, late 17th century Korean developed -소 as its main imperative, and it received an "upgrade" to modern "하십시오체/합쇼체".

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert, but I will just leave here what I have found.

For 겸양법 (Some people call it "object honorification," but I am not sure whether it is a proper translation), Middle Korean had these three characters that were attached to verb stems when the endings started with a consonant (ㅂ became ㅸ when the endings started with a vowel):

1. ᄉᆞᆸ (when the stems end with ㄱ, ㅂ, ㅅ,  ㅀ, or ㅎ)
2. ᅀᆞᆸ (when the stems end with a vowel, or ㄴ, ㄹ, or ㅁ)
3. ᄌᆞᆸ (when the stems end with ㄷ, ㄵ, ㅈ, or ㅊ)

According to 백문식 who wrote an etymology dictionary, those pre-endings (-ᄉᆞᆸ-, etc.) came from the verb [image: 시옷 아래아 리을 비읍]다. [image: 시옷 아래아 리을 비읍] meant 白 (to mention, to state, etc.).

At that time, the pre-ending -ᅌᅵ- was used for 공손법 (They call it "addressee honorification"). For example, 먹ᄂᆞ니ᅌᅵ다 is now interpreted as 먹습니다. Some characters including ㅿ, ᅌ, and ㆍ disappeared (ㅿ and ᅌ disappeared earlier than ㆍ) and honorification changed over time, which affected the characters I have just mentioned and [the following happened](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EA%B7%BC%EB%8C%80_%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%96%B4):

> -ᄉᆞᆸᄂᆞᅌᅵ다 ＞ -ᄉᆞᆸᄂᆡ다 ＞ -ᄉᆞᆸ늬다 ＞ -습니다

but, in consideration of several entries and example sentences in a dictionary, I can supplement the history with the following:

> -ᄉᆞᆸ- + -ᄂᆞ이다 → -ᄉᆞᆸᄂᆞ이다/ᄉᆞᆸ노이다 **＞＞** -습니다 (used after a consonant but not after ㄹ, ㅆ, or ㅄ) (1933) ＞ -습니다 (used after a consonant but not after ㄹ) (since 1989)

-습니다 is used for the "addressee honorification" not for the "object honorification." This shows a change in honorification.

The history of -습니까 can be said as the following:

> -ᄉᆞᆸ- + -닛가 ＞ -삽닛가/습닛가 (1934) ＞ -습니까 (since 1957)

-ᄂᆞ니잇가/ᄂᆞ닛가 (after a stem) and -니잇가/닛가 (after a stem or a pre-ending) were used to form "yes or no" questions. -습니까 can be used with or without interrogatives. It is quite natural that ㅅㄱ or ㅺ became ㄲ; for example, 아까 was once written as 앗가.

As for -읍시오, some believe that, after -ㅂ시다/읍시다 had been formed, -다 of -읍시다 got replaced with -오 to form imperative sentences.

> -(ᄋᆞᆸ)사ᅌᅵ다 ＞ -(ᄋᆞᆸ)새이다 ＞ -ㅂ새다/ㅂ세다 ＞ -ᄇ시다 ＞ -읍시다
>
> -읍시- + -오 → -읍시오

Nonetheless, it does not explain why -습시오 does not exist (-ᄉᆞᆸ시- existed before).

김현주 claims that people who were *not* well-versed in the court language used -ᄋᆞᆸ시- for the "addressee honorification" *when the subject of a sentence was equal to the addressee*. It seems that the author believes the following:

> -ᄉᆞᆸ- + -으시- → -ᄋᆞᆸ시-

According to the dissertation, such an unordinary combination became possible when -ᄉᆞᆸ- became used for the "addressee honorification" because -으시- was (and is) used for 존경법 ("subject honorification"). If this is the case, the absence of -습시오 is quite understandable.

**References**:

- [우리말샘](https://opendict.korean.go.kr)
- [중세국어(中世國語)](http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Item/E0053799)
- [공손법(恭遜法)](http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Item/E0079632)
- [근대 한국어](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EA%B7%BC%EB%8C%80_%ED%95%9C%EA%B5%AD%EC%96%B4)
- ['-ㄹ걸','-ㄹ껄'](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=77400)
- "우리말 어원 사전" (2014) by 백문식
- [국어 연감](https://korean.go.kr/nkview/kyear/nkyear2007/pdf/webzine.pdf) (2007) by 국립국어원
- [통합형 어미 '-습니다'류의 통시적 형성과 형태 분석](http://dl.nanet.go.kr/law/SearchDetailView.do?cn=KINX2007019742) (2006) by 정언학
- [국어 대우법 어미의 형태화 연구](https://koty.tistory.com/1275) (2010) by 김현주